# Ubuntu upgrade to 14.04 doesn't show after interrupted attempt

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, update-manager, partial-upgrade

I tried to update from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 using the update-manager. But the upgrade process stopped midway due to insufficient disk space. I cleared up enough space, and tried to resume by

```
    sudo update-manager -d
```

But the update manager doesn't show the upgrade to ubuntu 14.04 option anymore.

I tried the following

```
    sudo apt-get autoremove
    sudo apt-get clean
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

None of these help. Please help.
When I do

> lsb_release -a

now, I get

```
    LSB Version:    core-2.0-ia32:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-ia32:core-3.0-noarch:core-   
    3.1-ia32:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-ia32:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0- 
    noarch
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
    Release:    12.04
    Codename:   precise
```

Comment: Please provide output of `lsb_release -a` from terminal. There might be some issues, but sounds weird. Try that.

Comment: Please check the edit. I have provided the result. Please suggest some ideas.